# Error C1061 "... does not contain a definition for 'TextBox_TextChanged' ......." update SQL Server database with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, crud

I have a database table `Doctor` which contains columns `code_doctor` (varchar), `name` (varchar), `gender` (varchar), `salary` (int). I want to implement CRUD in this database, using Entity Framework. But, there's something wrong when trying to update data.

```
public partial class UpdatePage : Window
{
    DB_Rumah_Sakit_2697Entities _db = new DB_Rumah_Sakit_2697Entities();
    string code;

    public UpdatePage(string codedoc)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        code = codedoc;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dokter updateDoctor = (from m in _db.Doctors where m.kd_doctor == kode select m).Single();
        updateDoctor.code_doctor = textboxkode.Text;
        updateDoctor.name = textboxnama.Text;
        updateDoctor.gender = gendercombobox.Text;
        updateDoctor.salary= int.Parse(textboxgaji.Text);                    
            
        _db.SaveChanges();

        MainWindow.datagrid.ItemsSource = _db.Dokters.ToList();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be here:

```
from m in _db.Doctors where m.kd_doctor == kode
```

I don't see `kode` declared anywhere. Is that supposed to be `code`?

I would probably avoid mixing the linqQL with the fluent functions and just use Fluent:

```
Dokter updateDoctor = _db.Doctors.Single(x => x.kd_doctor == code);
```

Other than that nothing really stands out. From the exception it would look like you are possibly missing a `.Text` or such from one of your properties, though I'd suspect that would be in a query expression.

Is that the exact code you have in your application? On which line does the exception occur, on the `.Single()` or  `_db.SaveChanges()`?